# Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded. in RStudio on Mac

Tags: r, keras, rstudio

I have seen this question answered for issues in Windows but haven't seen any solution for a Mac.

After installing keras like:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(keras)
install_keras()
```

I get the error when running:

```
library(keras)
mnist <- dataset_mnist()

>> Error in initialize_python(required_module, use_environment) : 
  Python shared library not found, Python bindings not loaded.
```

I have tried the following:

```
use_python("/Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python3.7", required = TRUE)
use_virtualenv("~/MyFolder/.venv/")
use_python("~/MyFolder/.venv/bin/python")
```

But haven't been successful, I saw some suggestions about wrong python installation but it shouldn't be it in my case.
i have installed python 3.7.5 with Anaconda

```
=> python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

I'm on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.1 in RStudio, Version 1.2.5019. Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem with OSX. Found solution by configuring python virtual environment to use python3

```html
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

Comment: thanks, this worked for me. just had to add argument required=T `use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3", required=T)`

Answer (score 4):

This is a old thread, but just wanted to say for anyone that finds this that installing the python-dev package for whatever version of python you're using may work. I was using python3.8, so I installed python3.8-dev

Answer (score 0):

I had success pointing to the specific environment within the global tools options. From there you can add a specific install or point to conda environments.

Apply and restart session then run the python

[image]

[image]